# Push array increment and unique array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am pushing values in an array on Click in the Menu Component. The problem is that the key value is not incrementing more than 1. I need it so that i run logic to keep unique menu items, using filter.

Please see the sandbox.I hope it is opened. Please see the Menu component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-kepler-0htsx

The event is when you click OK of the modal, by selecting quantity. Please see images, The concerned code line is 46.
Navbar is the parent component having state.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Navv from "./Navv";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state={
Category:[
  {
    id:1,
    FoodType: "Chinese",
    Menu:["Egg Drop", "Chicken Fried", "Beef Fried"],
    Price:[2,8,10]
    },
    
    {
      id:2,
      FoodType: "Mexican",
      Menu:["Veg Burrito", "Chicken Burrito", "Beef Burrito"],
      Price:[7,8,10]
      }

],



listvalue:null,
Select_Item:null,
Select_Price:null,
Select_Quantity:null,
Select_Item_TotalPrice:null


  };




  render() {
    return (
   <React.Fragment>
      <Navv />

   <Menu


  Objs_Type={this.state.Category}

 
   />
   </React.Fragment>

    );


  }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Menu Component to be checked .Please see listval funciton. I want push array to have unique values. I wanted to run logic by using the key values, but if you select more than once, the key value does not exceed more than 1.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import NumericInput from 'react-numeric-input';



class Menu extends Component {
  state={

    addModalShow:false,
    copied: false,   
  };

;

  ModalShow=()=>{
    this.setState({addModalShow:true})
    
   };

   async ModalText(e){

   await this.setState({listvalue:e.target.innerHTML});

    //  console.log(this.state.listvalue);

   };

ModalClose=()=>{
 this.setState({addModalShow:false})
};


async Listval(){
 
let ll='$'+this.state.listvalue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

let ll2=this.state.listvalue.replace(/\d+/g, '');
let ll3=ll2.replace(/\$/g, '');

let ll4=ll.replace(/\$/g, '');
let ll5=this.state.Select_Quantity;
let ll6=parseFloat(ll4)*ll5;

let ll7=[this.state.Total_Item];
ll7.push(ll3);


  // this.state.ll7.map((e,idx) => {
  //   key={idx}
  // };

// for(var i=0;i<ll7.length;i++){
//   // push the component to elements!
//  return ll7[key=i]
// };

// ll7.filter((item,index)=>{
//   return ll7.indexOf(item)===index
// });



  // let ll2='$'+ll.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
 await  this.setState({ Select_Price: ll }); 
 await  this.setState({ Select_Item: ll3 }); 
 await  this.setState({ Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6 }); 

 await this.setState({Total_Item:ll7});



  

 console.log(this.state.Total_Item);
 
};


  stylesList={
  display: 'inline-block',
  background:"#C8C8C8",
  width:'500px',
  height:'50px'
  
  };

  
  onhover=(e)=> {
    e.target.style.background = 'red';
  
  };

  offhover=(e)=> {
    e.target.style.background = '#C8C8C8 ';
  };

 
  
  


  render() {


    return (
<div className="container-fluid">

            {this.Mapping_Type()}
            
 
        
      </div> 
    );

  }

  Mapping_Type (){

  
    let result_type = this.props.Objs_Type.map(a => a.FoodType);
    let result_menu = this.props.Objs_Type.map(a => a.Menu);
    let result_price=this.props.Objs_Type.map(a=>a.Price);
    
    let newFoodtype=[];
    let newMenu=[];
    let FoodType_Menu=[];
    let Price_new=[];
    for (let i=0;i<result_type.length; i++){
      
      let temp1=(<h1> Menu {result_type[i]}</h1>);
      let temp2=result_menu[i].map((item,idx)=>
      

      <div style={this.stylesList}>
      <ul style={{padding:0}}>
      {/* <CopyToClipboard> */}
      <li   id={idx} style={{listStyleType:'none'}} key={item.id} 
      className={"listitems"}
      onMouseOver={this.onhover}
      onMouseOut={this.offhover}
      onClick={(e)=>{this.ModalShow();this.ModalText(e)}}
      > {item } {result_price[i][idx]}  </li>
     {/* </CopyToClipboard> */}
    
    <Modal style={{opacity: 1}}

      size="md"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      show={this.state.addModalShow} 
      onHide={this.ModalClose}
    >
        
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Large Modal
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="container">
         {this.state.listvalue}
         <br />
         <NumericInput min={1} max={1000} value={this.state.Select_Quantity} 
         onChange={value => this.setState({Select_Quantity: value })} 
         style={{ float: 'right',
  width: '500px', padding: '10px'}}/>

  <br />

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"
  onClick={()=>{this.Listval()}}
>OK</button>

         
          </div>
          </Modal.Body>
         
      </Modal>
    




     </ul> 
     
      </div>
     
)
      
    
        FoodType_Menu.push(temp1,temp2);
      
        }
        return FoodType_Menu
            };


 
  

}



export default Menu;
```

Thanks
sal

Comment: `let ll7=(this.state.Total_Item||[]).concat(ll3);` and you didn't save your updated code to the sandbox.  It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but the data structure does not look right

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried saving it. Please open the Menu component, if  the sandbox opens

Comment: Please check this sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-kepler-0htsx

Comment: Still not saved in the sandbox or you need to update the url.  There are a lot of problems and things missing in the code.  Too many to really help you with.  Recommendation is to reorganize the data structure of your state, and create your view component for displaying the cart first.